# Best way to show default values for empty fields returned from a database query?

Tags: php, database

Is there a better way to write this code?

I want to show a default value ('No data') for any empty fields returned by the query:

```
$archivalie_id = $_GET['archivalie_id'];

$query =    "SELECT 
                a.*, 
                ip.description AS internal_project,
                o.description AS origin,
                to_char(ad.origin_date,'YYYY') AS origin_date  

            FROM archivalie AS a 
            LEFT JOIN archivalie_dating AS ad ON a.id = ad.archivalie_id                
            LEFT JOIN internal_project AS ip ON a.internal_project_id = ip.id
            LEFT JOIN origin AS o ON a.origin_id = o.id               

            WHERE a.id = $archivalie_id";

$result = pg_query($db, $query);

while ($row = pg_fetch_object($result))
{
    $no_data = '<span class="no-data">No data</span>';

    $internal_project = ($row->internal_project != '') ? $row->internal_project : $no_data; 
    $incoming_date = ($row->incoming_date != '') ? $row->incoming_date : $no_data; 
    $origin = ($row->origin != '') ? $row->origin : $no_data; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a small helper function

```
function dbValue($value, $default=null)
{
    if ($default===null) {
        $default='<span class="no-data">No data</span>';
    }
    if (!empty($value)) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is not just example code then you surely want to sanitize this query by writing...

```
$archivalie_id = pg_escape_string($_GET['archivalie_id']);
```

or you want to convert $archivalie_id with intval() if it is clearly always an integer.

furthermore I suggest to replace 'No data' with a constant like '_MYPROJECT_NODATA' so you can easily change the way your no data label looks or implement internationalisation.

You would then use

```
define('_MYPROJECT_NODATA', '<span class="no-data">No data</span>');
```

Comment: He's using the PostgreSQL extension, so the function to escape DB strings should be pg_escape_string().

Comment: Does it still need escaping if converted to an integer first?

Comment: @wdm: no, intval() is enough if it is indeed an integer, I adapted the post

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to select the default right on the database server.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(NULLIF(a.field1, ''), 'No data')       AS field1, 
  IFNULL(NULLIF(a.field2, ''), 'No data')       AS field2, 
  IFNULL(NULLIF(ip.description, ''), 'No data') AS internal_project,
  IFNULL(NULLIF(o.description, ''), 'No data')  AS origin,
  to_char(ad.origin_date,'YYYY') AS origin_date  
FROM 
  archivalie AS a 
  LEFT JOIN archivalie_dating AS ad ON a.id = ad.archivalie_id                
  LEFT JOIN internal_project  AS ip ON a.internal_project_id = ip.id
  LEFT JOIN origin            AS o  ON a.origin_id = o.id               
WHERE 
  a.id = $archivalie_id
```

This way you can output values right away, and you do not have to touch existing code. The `IFNULL(NULLIF())` turns empty strings to `NULL`, and `NULL` to `'No data'`. If you want to leave empty strings alone, use the `IFNULL()` only.

From an architectural perspective, this may lack some elegance (depending on how you look at it), but it is effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard SQL COALESCE function to return a special string instead of null, like this:

```
$query =    "SELECT 
            a.*, 
            COALESCE(ip.description,'NO_DATA') AS internal_project,
            COALESCE(o.description,'NO_DATA') AS origin,
            COALESCE(to_char(ad.origin_date,'YYYY'),'NO_DATA') AS origin_date
```

Then you could replace 'NO_DATA' by the appropriate HTML in your program as others have suggested.

Comment: What if the string 'NO_DATA' is a legitimate origin value, though?